# Find the surface area of the sphere inside the cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

The given equations are of a sphere and cylinder respectively
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=400$$
$$x^2+y^2=256$$
Solving the sphere equation for $z$ yields
$$z=\sqrt{400-x^2-y^2}$$
Now to find $ds$ we take the partial derivative of both $x$ and $y$, then square them to get
$$f_x=\frac{x^2}{400-x^2-y^2}$$
$$f_y=\frac{y^2}{400-x^2-y^2}$$
Then take those and adding one, and getting a common denominator, we get
$$\frac{20}{\sqrt{400-x^2-y^2}}$$
Then converting the above fraction to polar coordinates and taking the iterated integral
$$20\int_0^{16}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{\sqrt{400-r^2}}\,d\theta\,dr$$
and I get $320\pi$ but I guess I'm incorrect because the website we are using says I'm wrong. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: surface area of which region ? both spherical caps? plus lateral of cylinder ?

Comment: I shouldn't have said region as the question only states to find the surface of the portion of the sphere inside the cylinder.

Comment: so the two spherical caps

Comment: I'm not familiar with spherical caps so I can't answer that properly.

Comment: sure you are familiar with spherical caps, aka domes, with with cutting a sphere through a plane which might be off-center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface area inside the cylinder is

$$A=2\int_{S} \sqrt{1+ z_x^2+z_y^2}\> dx dy 
= 2\int_{S} \frac{20}{\sqrt{20^2 -(x^2+y^2)}}\> dx dy \\
=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{16} \frac{20}{\sqrt{20^2 -r^2}}\> rdrd\theta
=640\pi
$$